# Java applet security error

Tags: java, security, applet

Hi I'm wanting to test some applets and I'm just running it in my local browser from the file on my computer. But I am getting a security error

```
Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running
```

I am new to applets so maybe I am missing something out?
I am just using basic paint method and drawing.

how can I test this file on my own computer?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one of the following four things:

1. Sign your applet with an official certificate
2. Lower your security bar in the java system settings to medium
3. Sign your applet with an [self-signed applet](http://www.java.com/de/download/help/java_blocked.xml) and put your certificate in the java trust store
4. Put your URL to the [exception site list](http://www.java.com/en/download/exception_sitelist.jsp) of java

And please note that in some browsers you also have to enable the java plugin...

Answer (score 2):

Sine April 2013, even untrusted applets need to be signed with a valid certificate for "best user experience". See [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html) on Oracle's site. At the time of writing the current [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html) for 7u51 describe recent changes. The [Java Platform Group blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/) is worth reading.

If you're following an applet tutorial, updated online material is probably better than a book.

Comment: so how exactly would i test this locally on my own computer?